# Scala BitSet for Long value?

Tags: scala, bitset

I have a large dataset and the rowId is Long type.
It need to indicate whether one row is in some special set.

I found the BitSet more efficient for memory and network transport, but unlucky that the max value BitSet can hold is Int.

Is there some alternate way? (using boolean[]?)

Thanks

Comment: To represent 2^64 different longs as a bitset, you are going to need 2 petabytes of memory. That's hardly efficient :)

Comment: @Dima not sure that's what the op asked

Comment: @gurghet I am pretty sure that's what he asked :) I mean, maybe he _wanted to_ ask something different, that I don't know, but what he asked is this.

Comment: Thank you for the discussion.
Maybe the question could be better.
 
Actually I need a data structure to be more efficiency to indicate whether one row is in a given set.
In other words, to indicate whether one number is other set, in case there are very much numbers, especially in a distributed system, like Spark.

At first I thought BitSet may be good for memory and transport, but as @Dima said, when there are too many numbers, the bitset itself will cost significant memory, and it also possible that the numbers distrubited sparsely.

Comment: Well, there is no magic. You _do_ need at least one bit per number. 
So, if there are "too many numbers", and your requirement is to be able to definitively answer for every given number whether it is in a set or not, you are going to nee a _lot_ of memory.

Otherwise, there may be options. Perhaps, there aren't really that many numbers (just because the id is long, doesn't matter that the entire long domain is being used). Or, maybe, you don't mind some rare occurrence of a false positive (in that case, you want a `Bloom Filter`) ...

Comment: Finally I find the Roaring BitMap as the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The nature of `BitSet` makes it so that they can easily broken down and merged together to make network transport easy depending on what you are trying to achieve exactly.

You can always build your own however:

```
object BitSet extends BitSetFactory[BitSet] {
  val empty: BitSet = immutable.BitSet.empty
  def newBuilder = immutable.BitSet.newBuilder

  implicit def canBuildFrom: CanBuildFrom[BitSet, Long, BitSet] = bitsetCanBuildFrom
}

trait BitSetFactory[Coll <: BitSet with BitSetLike[Coll]] {
  def empty: Coll
  def newBuilder: Builder[Long, Coll]
  def apply(elems: Long*): Coll = (empty /: elems) (_ + _)
  def bitsetCanBuildFrom = new CanBuildFrom[Coll, Long, Coll] {
    def apply(from: Coll) = newBuilder
    def apply() = newBuilder
  }
}

trait BitSetLike[+This <: BitSetLike[This] with SortedSet[Long]] extends SortedSetLike[Long, This] { self =>
```

etc...

Comment: Thanks for shed me a light to expend the BitSet to hold more numbers.